# How to change port number of Couchbase console

Tags: couchbase

Unable to change the port number of Couchbase console.Its default 8091.
I am trying to append a line in the file known static_config file.
And the line is like-

```
{rest_port, 9000}.
```

Here is my screen short of the file.
[image]

Please help .Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the Administration Console port (8091) using the CLI, see this link:
http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/4.1/cli/cbcli/cluster-edit.html

Comment: Hi Kirk,
I am getting the error when I try to run the command .
ERROR: option cluster-ramsize is not specified.

Comment: Sorry. I think I put the command for an older version. I changed the answer to give you the link to the CLI reference for the newer versions of Couchbase.